# Wait angular response to load before using it in multiple components

Tags: angular, angular6

I have a service that loads data from my server, I want to have a response in this service that will be accessed by multiple components. The problem is, I have to wait the http response arrive. I know I can subscribe to the Observable, but then if I subscribe it in all the components I have it will load it in every component.
I want to be able to wait until it loaded in any component.

Here is my service:

**KalidataService**

```
export class KalidataService {
  public response: any = null;

  constructor(private http: Http) {
    this.getResponse();
  }

  getResponse() {
    const url = 'http://url.com';

    const params = new URLSearchParams();

    params.append('login', 'login');

    params.append('senha', 'pass');

    this.http.post(url, params).subscribe(
      response => this.response = response.json(),
      error => console.log('ERROR')
    );

  }
}
```

Here is one of my components:

```
export class DiarioComponent implements OnInit {
  nome_usario: string;
  materias: Materia[];


  constructor(private kalidataService: KalidataService) {
  }

  log() {
    console.log(this.kalidataService.response);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Eg: I have the function log in a button, when I click right after loading the page it logs 'null' after a while if I click it logs the response.

Comment: Using Resolvers in Routes??

Comment: Have a look at `BehaviorSubjects`, it's an awesome way to let components communicate each other. Or use resolvers in route, or if you have problems in authenticating, just use a Guard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this using Subject/BehaviorSubject().

**KalidataService**

```
private subjectData = new Subject<any>();
public subjectData$ = this.subjectData.asObservable();

getResponse() {
    const url = 'http://url.com';

    const params = new URLSearchParams();

    params.append('login', 'login');

    params.append('senha', 'pass');

    this.http.post(url, params).subscribe(
      response => {
        this.response = response.json();
        this.subjectData.next(this.response);
      },
      error => console.log('ERROR')
    );

  }
```

**DiarioComponent**

```
ngOninit(){
   this.kalidataService.subjectData$.subscribe((response)=>{
       console.log(response);
   });
}
```